# GTLRDrive_File object missing modifiedTime and createdTime properties

Tags: ios, swift, google-drive-api, google-api-client

I'm working with the `Google API Client for REST` Swift SDK, and I'm trying to parse out `modifiedTime` and `createdTime` from the API response containing `GTLRDrive_File` objects.

But they don't appear to be there? Here's an example of the payload I'm getting from `po file`:

```
GTLRDrive_File 0x60c00084eb20: {
    mimeType:"audio/mpeg"     
    id:"1xt8eqYit3tOrZUeuG9V7_dsq60Iq9xVC" 
    kind:"drive#file" 
    name:"Lobo_Loco_-_15_-_Save_the_Bees_ID_817 (2).mp3" 
}
```

What's going on? I wouldn't expect these properties to be optional?

Here's the code I'm using to loop after querying:

```
if let files = result.files as? [GTLRDrive_File] {
    for file in files {
        print(file.modifiedTime, file.createdTime)
    }
}
```

(And of course both are nil).

How can I get modified/created dates from a `GTLRDrive_File`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the request (file.list, etc) was successful `createdTime`, `modifiedTime` which can be found in the [Drive File Resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource), can be accessed by first accessing 'files' object.

So if you go to [Try-it](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list#try-it):

Use `files(createdTime)` as parameter in the 'field' property and it will return those fields. (Use files.list as sample).

In the iOS SDK, simply:

```
let query = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesList.query()
query.fields = "files(createdTime,modifiedTime)"
```

will work.

Comment: OK, got that working. Thanks! Added an edit to your answer to expand on it a bit.